# Laravel : merge two models and groupBy the result

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections, group-by, merge

I have two models and merged them and try to groupby them  with sum of column:

```
public function getCards()
    {
        $home_cards_games=Game::groupBy('home_club_id')->selectRaw(' home_club_id ,SUM(home_cards) as cards')->orderBy('cards','desc')->get(); 

        foreach($home_cards_games as $home_cards_game){
           
            $home_cards_game->club=$home_cards_game->homeclub->club;
            unset($home_cards_game->homeclub);
        }
        $away_cards_games=Game::groupBy('away_club_id')->selectRaw(' away_club_id ,SUM(away_cards) as cards')->orderBy('cards','desc')->get();

       foreach($away_cards_games as $away_cards_game){
       
        $away_cards_game->club=$away_cards_game->awayclub->club;
        unset($away_cards_game->awayclub);   
       }
```

Now I merged both models $home_cards_games and $away_cards_games :

```
    $all_cards=collect();
           foreach($home_cards_games as $home_cards_game){
            $all_cards->push($home_cards_game);
           }
           foreach($away_cards_games as $away_cards_game){
            $all_cards->push($away_cards_game);
           }
return $all_cards;
    }
```

the return result is like this :

```
[
  {
    "home_club_id": 52,
    "cards": 2,
    "league": "Serie A",
    "club": "Udinese"
  },
  {
    "home_club_id": 39,
    "cards": 0,
    "league": "LaLiga Santander",
    "club": "Mallorca"
  },
  {
    "home_club_id": 2,
    "cards": 0,
    "league": "Premier League",
    "club": "Man Utd"
  },
```

No I want to group the collection by clubs and sum them cards, I did this :

```
   $all_cards=$all_cards->groupBy('club')->selectRaw(' club ,SUM(cards) as card')->orderBy('card','desc')->get(); // error is here
```

i get this error : `Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::selectRaw does not exist.`
How can I solve this?

**Notice**

when I print type of return it print : `object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by this :
I changed :

```
$all_cards=collect();
           foreach($home_cards_games as $home_cards_game){
            $all_cards->push($home_cards_game);
           }
           foreach($away_cards_games as $away_cards_game){
            $all_cards->push($away_cards_game);
           }
```

to :

```
$all_cards=collect();
       foreach($home_cards_games as $home_cards_game){
        foreach($away_cards_games as $away_cards_game){
            if($home_cards_game->club == $away_cards_game->club){
                $home_cards_game->cards = $home_cards_game->cards+$away_cards_game->cards;
            }
           }
        $all_cards->push($home_cards_game);
       }
```

also I removed this line :

```
$all_cards=$all_cards->groupBy('club')->selectRaw(' club ,SUM(cards) as card')->orderBy('card','desc')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like,

```php
$cards = Game::groupBy('club')->selectRaw(' club ,SUM(cards) as card')->orderBy('card','desc')->get();

$all_cards->merge($cards->toArray());
```

Comment: I don't have problem with $home_cards_games ,just error in line `$all_cards=$all_cards->groupBy('club')->selectRaw(' club ,SUM(cards) as card')->orderBy('card','desc')->get();`

Comment: @Sermedmayi You've defined `$all_cards` as a collection. On Laravel `collect()` helper, `groupBy` method is available, but `selectRaw` is not. You can store the query result in some another variable and then push the data to `$all_cards`

Comment: @Sermedmayi I've updated my answer. I hope it'll help.

Comment: Oh... My bad. I pasted a buggy code. I've updated the solution.